# Jquery wont animate no matter what in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

My jquery code gets the "click" function, but does not animate, it just "jumps" without animation. Been struggling with it for hours now.

Jquery code

```
$( document ).ready(function() {


// Navigation

  $('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var target = this.hash;
  var $target = $(target);

  $('html, body').stop().animate({
      'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
  }, 5, 'swing', function () {
      window.location.hash = target;
         });
     });
  });
```

HTML Code

```
        <!-- Content -->
<div class="slideBg" id="slideBg">
       <!-- NAVBAR -->
       <div class="row header">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top col-md-8 col-md-offset-2" role="navigation">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header ">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav menu col-xs-12 col-xs-offset-6 ol-md-12 col-md-offset-6 col-lg-12 col-lg-offset-6">
                <li><a  href="#slideBg"><img class="menuImage" src="img/Slide1/Header/menu/mugIcon.png" alt=""><span class="menuItem">AVALEHT</span></a></li>
                <li><a  href="#slide2"><img class="menuImage" src="img/Slide1/Header/menu/menuIcon.png" alt=""><span class="menuItem">MENÜÜ</span></a></li>
                <li><a  href="#slide3"><img class="menuImage" src="img/Slide1/Header/menu/locationIcon.png" alt=""><span class="menuItem">ASUKOHT</span></a></li>
                <li><a class="" href="#slide4"><img class="menuImage" src="img/Slide1/Header/menu/meistIcon.png" alt=""><span class="menuItem">MEIST</span></a></li>
              </ul>
            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
          </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </nav>

      </div>
      <!-- /NAVBAR -->
      <div class="slide1" id="slide1">
       <img class="s1Logo helper" src="img/Slide1/Logo/logo.png" alt="">
       <div class="nool"></div>
     </div>
   </div>



    <div class="slide2" id="slide2">
         <ul class="sideMenu">
          <li id="ahjukoogid" class="sMenuItem dashed">Ahjukoogid</li>
          <li id="magusadAmpsud" class="sMenuItem dashed">Magusad Ampsud</li>
          <li id="plaadikoogid" class="sMenuItem dashed">Plaadikoogid</li>
          <li id="soolasedAmpsud" class="sMenuItem dashed">Soolased Ampsud</li>
          <li id="tordid" class="sMenuItem dashed">Tordid</li>
          <li id="tordiloigud" class="sMenuItem dashed">Tordilõigud</li>
          <li id="tryhvlid" class="sMenuItem dashed">Trühvlid</li>
          <li id="quiche" class="sMenuItem dashed">Quiche</li>
        </ul>

    <div class="tryhvlid">
      <!-- Nimed ja Hinnad -->
    </div>
    <div class="nool"></div>
  </div>



     <div class="slide3" id="slide3">
    asd
           <div class="nool"></div>
         </div>

           <div class="slide4" id="slide4">
    asd
           <div class="nool"></div>
         </div>
```

I have tried multiple things. Tried different ways to get the animation work. I also tested if the document.ready function is ran with alert, it is. I checked if the jquery gets the click function and it does. everything seesm to work, but just it doesnt animate or scroll smoothly.

Comment: No errors in the console?

Comment: try setting the time to something larger `, 5, 'swing'` -> `, 5000, 'swing'` - time is measured in milliseconds in jQuery

Comment: Thats right, forgot to add. No errors in the console. Tried it, If I set longer time, it will just take longer to "jump" to the page.

Comment: I am very unclear what you're trying to do? You're clicking the link and trying to animate to the offset. How do you expect it would animate to the same offset position?

Answer (score 2):

This is because in the `duration` parameter for the animation you're passing `5` which is interpreted as 5 milliseconds. Try something like 5000 if you want a 5 second animation.

```
 $('html, body').stop().animate({
      'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
  }, 5000, 'swing', function () {
      window.location.hash = target;
      });
   });
});
```

**EDIT**

> Apparently this is a known issue. jQuery's `animate()` doesn't play nice in Chrome when setting the `x-overflow` property of html/body to hidden. Instead it ends up skipping the animation altogether. See [this thread for more information](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/2215).

Comment: Tried it before, If I set longer time, it will just take longer to "jump" to the page.

Comment: @JoosepSisas What exactly are you expecting from your animation? For the amount of content you have in your example a duration around 500 milliseconds should give the desired effect.

Comment: Im expecting it to go the offset smoothly, but right now it jumps instantly. And it jumps no matter how long the duration is. If I set duration longer, it will just wait 500ms and then jump.

Comment: @JoosepSisas It scrolls smoothly for me in this fiddle -->https://jsfiddle.net/xhuuj0he/8/

Comment: @JoosepSisas Where are you using this code that it's not working? What browser, version, website, etc...The more information you share with us the easier it is for us to help you.

Comment: I tried the same website on IE, and it worked. But it doesnt work on chrome. Any ideas?

Comment: @JoosepSisas See this issue thread, it seems to be what you're running into - https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/2215 . Unfortunately I don't have access to chrome right now but I'd try removing the `overflow-x: hidden;` in your css and see if that fixes the issue in Chrome.

Comment: Add it to the answers, so i can mark it that way.. it worked.. :O

Comment: @JoosepSisas Would you mind marking my answer as correct when you get a chance?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you expect to achieve. Have you tried without using `swing`? Something like this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  // Navigation
  $('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var target = $(this).attr('href');
    var $target = $(target);

    $('html, body').animate({
      'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
    }, 'slow');
  });
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xeqcyume/)

Comment: without swing, the same... just jumps to offset

Comment: Have you looked at the fiddle? It scrolls down slowly when you click on a link.

Comment: Does this fiddle scroll smoothly for you? jsfiddle.net/60mb01mz/11 The fiddle that was provided, yes it scrolled smoothly, but when I copy pasted it into the new files and ran it.. just jumped again, no animation. Maybe it's a conflict somwhere?

Comment: So you got it working then :) Maybe you are not loading jQuery properly on your system.

Comment: Okay I figured it out... everything works perfectly at internet explorer and edge... on chrome it is not working, any ideas?